# Scheme Resources For People with Lisp experience

Tags: scheme

I would like to use scheme (gambit-c) for a personel project. I have experience with clojure and familiarity with common lisp. I am looking for books/documents that will quickly get me up to speed with scheme's idiosyncrasies something like the oreilly's pocket reference series.

Answer (score 2):

The best introductory tutorial must be [Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum Days](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/t-y-scheme/t-y-scheme.html) by Dorai Sitaram. Kent Dybvig's [The Scheme Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/) provides a full coverage of the R5RS specification of the language and teaches how to write idiomatic Scheme code. If you are working with the latest specification (R6RS), see [the 4th edition of the same book](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/).

Answer (score 0):

It is sad that someone like me with next-to-nothing scheme or lisp experience should have to answer this question, but because nobody has answered you so far, I'll try.  The only scheme book I have read is *The Little Schemer* (I own *The Seasoned Schemer*, but have not leveled up enough for that yet).  The authors point out syntactic differences between scheme and lisp throughout the two books, mostly in short, cute footnotes.  It is all core language differences, nothing to do with libraries of any sort.  I always thought that those notes would be useful to me one day when I might have to move between scheme and list.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The Little Schemer books are great, and well worth reading. But the subset of Scheme that they use is quite small, and might not be enough to get someone very familiar with Common Lisp up to speed in Scheme, but would explain surface syntactic differences like `define` vs `defun` etc.